# I can't display this file for some reason

Tags: python, image, printing

The file I am trying to show is a normal text file.

Here's the code I wrote so far:

```
import os                      

THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, r' C:\Users\dylan\PycharmProjects\Crooms terminal\ Welcome to the crooms terminal.txt')

for name in my_file:
    with open(name, "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        frames.append(f.readlines())

print(my_file)
for frame in frames:
    print("".join(frame))
```

And here is the image I am trying to print

```
  _____                                 _______                  _             _ 
 / ____|                               |__   __|                (_)           | |
| |     _ __ ___   ___  _ __ ___  ___     | | ___ _ __ _ __ ___  _ _ __   __ _| |
| |    | '__/ _ \ / _ \| '_ ` _ \/ __|    | |/ _ \ '__| '_ ` _ \| | '_ \ / _` | |
| |____| | | (_) | (_) | | | | | \__ \    | |  __/ |  | | | | | | | | | | (_| | |
 \_____|_|  \___/ \___/|_| |_| |_|___/    |_|\___|_|  |_| |_| |_|_|_| |_|\__,_|_|
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: `my_file` is a path name to a single file. When you say `for name in my_file` what do you expect `name` to be?

Comment: What do you get if you `print(my_file)`?

Comment: `Crooms terminal\ Welcome ` looks dodgy. Do you really have a file name which starts with a space?

Comment: How can you append something to `frames` when it hasn't been defined anywhere?

Comment: Why are you trying to `path.join` onto the start of an absolute path?

Comment: Sorry everyone for not being more specific about what my problem didn't think this many people would respond . Anyway /Peter Wood/ The reason how I now its not working to due to the fact that the pycharm is was giving me this error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 7, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'

Comment: For the next question  /Peter wood/what I was trying to do was make a my_file a variable to my file path with as you can see is not working for me

Comment: /Peter Wood/ Yes , it does have a space in it and I tried with and without the space and it was still was not working.

Comment: /Peter Wood/ Ok so the part were you mention about me appending frames and then I did't define it any were so that's my fault

Comment: /khelwood/ So the reason why I put the path.join was because I added a animation to switch in between two text files for a specific  time to display kind of like a animation in the terminal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you pasted is not formatted right and I see many things that could be wrong...

For ex. `frames` and `file` are not defined

There are some extra spaces in the path, ...

But here's how I would do it:

```
#THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
my_file = os.path.join(r"d:\temp", 'terminal.txt')
frames = []
#for name in my_file:
with open(my_file, "r") as f:
    frames.append(f.readlines())
print(my_file)
for frame in frames:
    print("".join(frame))
```

Also a very easy way to show the content of a file would be something like this:

```
my_file = os.path.join(r"d:\temp", 'terminal.txt')
with open(my_file, "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the example of code I will let you know if it works out

Comment: Also I already tried the very easy and it gave me this error  File "<input>", line 2
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
Which what I thought means I need to put it in a 8 bit encoding utcf thing  but I don't no where I would put the code , Thats my main problem I was having.